# SQL Server update statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a script to update the duplicate contact and all its tables where it is referenced.

One of the update statements that I have is the following:

```
/* update the contactid, and the compcontactid on the compcontact table */
UPDATE cmpc
SET cmpc.contactid = tt.contactid,
    cmpc.compcontactid = (SELECT MAX(cc.compcontactid) 
                          FROM compcontact cc 
                          INNER JOIN @tempDupContacts tdup ON tdup.contactid = cc.contactid 
                          INNER JOIN @tempTable tt ON tt.namefml = tdup.namefml) 
FROM compcontact cmpc
INNER JOIN @tempDupContacts tdup ON tdup.contactid = cmpc.contactid
INNER JOIN @tempTable tt ON tt.namefml = tdup.namefml
```

However, when I run the script (script is way tooo long to post here), I get the following error:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 255
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.compcontact' with unique index 'XPKcompcontact'. The duplicate key value is (A000UZCU, A00JTCAP, X00GM2NF).

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and what the fix would be?

Is this because It is attempting to update the value that has the

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to update a unique key value to a value that already exists in the column. This is not allowed, since each value in the unique key *must be unique*.

Answer (score 0):

As @sion_corn said, you're trying to update a column having unique key constraint. 
Try adding a WHERE clause in your update statement to exclude the value which already exists.

For example:

```
UPDATE cmpc
SET cmpc.contactid = tt.contactid,
    cmpc.compcontactid = (SELECT MAX(cc.compcontactid) 
                      FROM compcontact cc 
                      INNER JOIN @tempDupContacts tdup ON tdup.contactid = cc.contactid 
                      INNER JOIN @tempTable tt ON tt.namefml = tdup.namefml     
                      WHERE cc.compcontactid <> cmpc.compcontactid) 
FROM compcontact cmpc
INNER JOIN @tempDupContacts tdup ON tdup.contactid = cmpc.contactid
INNER JOIN @tempTable tt ON tt.namefml = tdup.namefml 
WHERE cmpc.contactid <> tt.contactid
```

Comment: By adding a where clause it will stop the error, however there can be value in that error coming back so that you know your data hasn't been saved.